# NFC stacks on Android OS

Tags: android, sdk, nfc, open-nfc

Can someone help me understanding the current state of the NFC Android stack? With the **OS 2.3** there was released small NFC support (limited only to NXP tags reading), later the Google augment the API, so in **OS 2.3.3** the wider range of tags is supported and also p2p is possible.

My question is how the **Open NFC** stack (http://www.open-nfc.org/) fits into current state?

As I understand the Open NFC stack is parallel activity and is optional replacement to the current stack. Due to its description it overcomes some limits of the Google NFC stack implementation and makes new HW adaptions (i.e. support for new tag types) easier…

To my understanding this stack is intended to by used by device manufacturers, not mobile developers – is that right? Or is it possible to download the Open NFC stack, compile it as a library, put into .apk and use as an alternative the Google stack?

But even it will be possible for application developers to use the Open NFC stack – does it make sense with the new 2.3.3 OS features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone help me understanding the
>   current state of the NFC Android
>   stack? With the OS 2.3 there was
>   released small NFC support (limited
>   only to NXP tags reading), later the
>   Google augment the API, so in OS 2.3.3
>   the wider range of tags is supported
>   and also p2p is possible.
>
> My question is how the Open NFC stack
>   (http://www.open-nfc.org/) fits into
>   current state??

At the moment (Android 2.3.4), the Android platform does not integrate the Open NFC stack. This stack has several advantages: not limited to one particular NFC hardware, portable to many different environments (not only Android), many additional features compared to the current stack. On the other hand, because Open NFC is not part of the standard Android environment, it requires some work (but it is actually quite easy) to use this stack in an Android platform. The Open NFC documentation describes this process.

> As I understand the Open NFC stack is
>   parallel activity and is optional
>   replacement to the current stack. Due
>   to its description it overcomes some
>   limits of the Google NFC stack
>   implementation and makes new HW
>   adaptions (i.e. support for new tag
>   types) easier…

Correct.

> To my understanding this stack is
>   intended to by used by device
>   manufacturers, not mobile developers –
>   is that right? Or is it possible to
>   download the Open NFC stack, compile
>   it as a library, put into .apk and use
>   as an alternative the Google stack?

Unfortunately, because the standard Android kernel does not support modules loading, the Open NFC stack cannot be simply installed as another application, it requires a kernel change. But once the kernel is replaced, it is quite easy to deploy and use the Open NFC stack.

> But even it will be possible for
>   application developers to use the Open
>   NFC stack – does it make sense with
>   the new 2.3.3 OS features?

An application developer should probably stick to the OS features, even if more limited, since they assure the portability of the code over any NFC-enabled phone. But if you are trying to use "more" features than what comes with Android, Open NFC is a good candidate.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

> To my understanding this stack is intended to by used by device manufacturers, not mobile developers – is that right?

According to the Open NFC site, yes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer - this was also my understanding, but not being an Android guru I prefer to ask you - real experts. Means, until some phone manufacturer will integrate the stack into device, it does not make too much sense to be interested in Open NFC stack.... My impression is also that with 2.3.3 from application developer point of view the Google API has more or less similar functions as the Open NFC API promises to have...

Comment: @STeN: "until some phone manufacturer will integrate the stack into device, it does not make too much sense to be interested in Open NFC stack" -- an app developer cannot make use of Open NFC unless it is on hardware. "the Google API has more or less similar functions as the Open NFC API promises to have" -- I am not expert enough in NFC to be able to make that claim, sorry.